# Creating Wordpress "Stand alone" plugin in Themosis Framework

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Themosis Framework provides (laravel like) MVC type development environment for wordpress.

It all look great, but just got stuck in developing a "stand alone" plugin, because plugin look for configuration files in higher level directory.

This is how root directory look like

```
        +-- app/
        |  +-- Console
        |  +-- Exceptions
        |  +-- Forms
        |  +-- Hooks
        |  +-- Http
           |  +-- Controllers
        |  +-- Mail
        |  +-- Providers
        |  +-- Widgets
        +-- bootstrap/
        +-- config/
        |  +-- app.php
        |  +-- ...
        |  +-- wordpress.php
        +-- database/
        +-- htdocs/
        |  +-- cms/
        |  +-- content/
        |  +-- index.php
        |  +-- wp-config.php
        +-- resources/
        |  +-- languages/
        |  +-- views/
        +-- routes/
        |  +-- console.php
        |  +-- web.php
        +-- storage/
        +-- tests/
        +-- vendor/
        +-- .env
        +-- composer.json
        +-- console
        +-- wp-cli.yml
```

this is how plugin directory look like in /htdocs/content/plugins:

```
        +-- assets
        +-- config
        +-- dist
        +-- inc
        +-- languages
        +-- resources
        +-- views
        +-- package.json
        +-- plugin-name.php
        +-- routes.php
        +-- webpack.mix.js
```

Themosis has interesting feature of compiling (although its php based framework) so I thought compiling will create some asset to make plugin work as standalone plugin.

but it seems error (plugin looking for resources stored in higher level directory) still remain

Would anyone know if making "standalone" plugin is possible using themosis framework?

Thank you!

Comment: Read this - https://framework.themosis.com/docs/2.0/plugin ?

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you. yes we've read this installed the framework and tested. but still not sure how it works. 

"The plugin is configured to work on a Themosis framework like environment only."

this is what they say on github, which makes us more confused...